# SSH / SFTP Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: permissions, ssh, openssh, sftp

I've added the following to my sshd_config

```
Match Group sftponly
ChrootDirectory /srv/sftpfolder
ForceCommand internal-sftp
#AllowTcpForwarding no
PermitTunnel no
X11Forwarding no
```

I created "user" by
`useradd -g sftponly user`
`mkdir -p /home/user/.ssh`
And then created authorized_keys in the users ssh folder.

Permissions on `/home/user/.ssh/` is 700 and on the authorized_keys file 600.

But when I try `sftp -P 12345 user@ip-address` I get.

```
sftp -P 12345 -v user@ip-address
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/home/user/.ssh/master-d986de8e7074586561615461cc918c33db0e1d57" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to ip-address [185.104.140.216] port 12345.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ip-address:12345 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:/Pd8kuuE858qr7V6RZhdMw8u+3xbxp/CZGVtinPfUmU
debug1: Host '[ip-address]:12345' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:66x60sLHiBKnCaV4hjwStZBp3SJczxVw7WhWouQECWQ /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@ip-address: Permission denied (publickey).
Connection closed
```

Am I missing something?
Logging in with root works as expected...

Comment: Which keys are in authorized_keys?

Comment: the one for "user" from the client machine the `id_rsa.pub`

Comment: What happens if you force ssh to try the id_rsa private key file? https://superuser.com/questions/772660/howto-force-ssh-to-use-a-specific-private-key

Comment: The same unfortunately

Comment: When you made the directory for the user as root user - did you them go and set those directories as being owned by the user?

Comment: Yes. The home dir is owend by the user and the group belonging to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it. Turns out I've set the permissions correctly for the authorized_keys files and the home dir of the user. However the owner was root:sftponly